# How to pattern match abstract parent classes in a inheritance tree

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

I am new to scala with a java background.

Is there a way to pattern match super classes (or traits) in a class inheritance tree with leafs as case classes and nodes abstract classes or traits? As far as I know case class inheritance is not allowed.

I think that pattern matching abstract classes in large inheritance tree would be very helpful

In the following code the last case in the match statement errors during compilation

```scala
sealed trait Person {
   def name: String
}

case class Customer(name: String, email: String) extends Person

sealed trait Employee extends Person {
   def id: Int
}

case class Worker(name: String, id: Int, skills: Array[String]) extends Employee

case class Manager(name: String, id: Int, title: String) extends Employee

def process(p: Person) = p match {
   case Customer(_, email) => email
   case Employee(name, _) => name + "@acme.com"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were missing the `name` field in `Employee` and an `unapply` method in the companion object of `Employee`:

```
sealed trait Employee extends Person {
  def id: Int
  def name: String
}

object Employee {
  def unapply(e: Employee): Option[(String, Int)] =
    Option(e) map { e =>
      (e.name, e.id)
    }
}
```

With the above changes the process method gives no problems:

```
def process(p: Person) = p match {
  case Customer(_, email) => email
  case Employee(name, _) => name + "@acme.com"
}
```

Comment: This is very close to case classes. However when I set 'name' to constant value the pattern match doesn't work (Eg: case Employee("John", _) => "john@bar.com"). Can my unapply method support this kind of filtering?

Comment: It should already work. For me it does actually: `println(process(Worker("Erik", 2, Array.empty)))` and I have this in `process`: `case Employee("Erik", _) => "erik@acme.com"`

Answer (score 3):

It's not that fancy (as others may suggest with structural types,) but it's quite practical, I think:

```
def process(p: Person) = p match {
   case Customer(_, email) => email
   case e: Employee => e.name + "@acme.com"
}
```

If you need to match against some particular known value you may use guards:

```
def process(p: Person) = p match {
   case Customer(_, email) => email
   case e: Employee if e.name == "Joe" => e.name + "@acme.com"
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. Your code solves the problem with the email but I am looking for a general approach. Basically I would like to pattern match in a similar way to case classes